# how to use array in where clause in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter, trying to use an array in where clause and return only those id match with array.

Submitted by form:

`$arrTID = $this->input->post('Present'); 
print_r($arrTID);`

output:

```
Array(
 [0]=>FMM003
 [1]=>30089
 [2]=>30097
)
```

When use in foreach:

```
foreach($arrTID as $key=>$ID){               
 print_r($ID);
}
```

output: FMM0033008930097

query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("select TraineeID from tbl_attendance_processed where TraineeID IN $ID and attnDate='$atnDate'");
$res=$query->result_array();
```

I'm actually need that query return those ID in array which match with this query. How do get this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$arrTID = $this->input->post('Present');
$atnDate = $this->input->post('atnDate');

$this->db->select('TraineeID');
$this->db->where_in('TraineeID', $arrTID);
$this->db->where('attnDate', $atnDate);
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_attendance_processed');

// and fetch result
$res = $query->result(); // as object
$res = $query->result_array(); // as array
```

and learn this http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_check = array(10,11,12,13);
$name = "Raj Shekhar";

$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->where_in('id', $array_check);

$this->db->where('name', $name);

$query = $this->db->get('table_name');

// return result as array
return $query->result_array();
```